# Update Bundle getCharSequence in Android

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am having a big problem with Bundle, Intent and Android.

I send an SMS and therefore I create a Bundle with its text and number in it.
Now when I want to change my number and my text, my application always sends the same first SMS.

I have tried nearly everything but I do not know how to solve my problem!

What I tried was that:
Updating my PendingIntent with a FLAG, but it does not help.

Maybe, someone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Parkschein.this, MyAlarmService.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsNumber", smsNumber);
bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsText", smsText);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Parkschein.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Parkschein.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);

if(smsMinutes.equals(""))
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
else {
Long smsMinutesInLong = Long.parseLong(smsMinutes);
                      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), smsMinutesInLong*60000, pendingIntent);
}
```

and here is my service class, where the sms is sent:

```
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStart(intent, startId);

  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT + PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle = intent.getExtras();

  smsNumberToSend = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraSmsNumber");
  smsTextToSend = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraSmsText");

 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumberToSend, null, smsTextToSend, null, null);
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Android caches objects like `PendingIntent` for later usage. Are you sure you've added flags to correct PE? You probably need to do this

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Parkschein.this, 0, myIntent, 
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```